# Only using a class within another class

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

```
        public class ClientData : IEquatable<ClientData>
        {
            public String CustomerName { get; set; }
            public int CustomerId { get; set; }        

            public bool Equals(ClientData other)
            {
                if (other == null) return false;
                return (CustomerName == other.CustomerName && CustomerId == other.CustomerId);
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                int hash = 23;
                hash = hash * 31 + CustomerName.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 31 + CustomerId.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }

        }
```

and

```
public class Service
{
    ....
}
```

I'm looking for a way to use my ClientData but only within my service class i.e only the service class knows that the clientdata class exists and can use its methods normally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it a nested class e.g.:

```
public class Service
{
    private class ClientData : IEquatable<ClientData>
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make `CientData` a `private` nested class of `Service`:

```
public class Service
{
    private class ClientData
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By making `ClientData` a nested class of `Service`, as per below, `Service` can create instances of `ClientData` and access all its `public` methods, but cannot expose it publicly to other classes, and other classes cannot instantiate `ClientData`.

```
public class Service
{
    private class ClientData : IEquatable<ClientData>
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
    private ClientData _clientData = new ClientData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either make the ClientData class nested in the Service class, or make the ClientData class `protected` and have them in the same assembly.